# Javascript add dynamic function to an object

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to add a function to an object without knowing it's name in advance?

I do something like:

```
var $functionName = "sayHello"; 

object."$functionName" = function (args) {
     // Do stuff 
} 

/// Later

object.sayHello ("Henry");
```

Comment: Unrelated: Is it a PHP _influence_ to name variables starting with `$`? Or jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
var functionName = "sayHello";

anObject[functionName] = function (args) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that `a.b` is syntactic sugar for `a["b"]` -- they mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the array format for this:

`object[$functionName] = function () {}`